# Yesod scaffolded site browserId TlsException

Tags: authentication, ssl, docker, yesod

#### What I want to do

Create and authenticate users with `BrowserId` in Yesod.

#### What I've tried

I haven't altered the authentication code from the scaffolded site. My reading of the following in `Foundation.hs` suggests this would create a new user when they authenticate with browserId.

```
getAuthId creds = runDB $ do
    x <- getBy $ UniqueUser $ credsIdent creds
    case x of
        Just (Entity uid _) -> return $ Just uid
        Nothing -> Just <$> insert User
            { userIdent = credsIdent creds
            , userPassword = Nothing
            }
```

But when I authenticate with BrowserId/Persona I get a page with the following error message:

```
TlsException (HandshakeFailed (Error_Protocol ("certificate rejected: [SelfSigned]",True,CertificateUnknown)))
```

I can't find the file generating this. At first I thought serving the site over https might solve it but I've now implemented https and it doesn't. I'm using a signed, CA cert.

#### Expected behaviour

Authenticating an existing user should sign them in. Authenticating a previously unknown user should add them.

Can anyone shed light on what I've missed?

#### Edit: `tls-retreivecertificate` output

Running `tls-retrievecertificate mydomain.com 443 --verify --chain` shows that my site is returning its certificate and the signing authority's one successfully but resulting in failure for an `UnknownCA`.

Running `tls-retrievecertificate twitter.com 443 --verify --chain` **also** shows certificates and an `UnknownCA`.

I therefore think the problem here is on the machine running my Yesod app or in my proxy settings rather than with how I've installed the certificate on the machine running the web server (both are actually Docker containers so I'm using the word 'machine' broadly). I'm looking for a solution and will post one if I find it. In the meantime all help gratefully received. My Nginx setup is as follows:

```
# see http://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf#comment730384_577370
upstream localhost {
    server api_1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl.dkey;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow the TLS debugging steps at: https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-tls#common-issues

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Thanks for the tip — I've edited the question to reflect the information that got me. This will probably end up being a 'kicking myself for missing it' situation but right now I'm still stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a Docker problem rather than a Yesod one. The Docker container running the app had no trusted certificates so I simply rebuilt it and `ADD`ed the ones from the host machine. Problem solved.